# Rapid fire with logitech lua script?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

When writing lua scripts for my logitech g502, I've gotten rapid fire to work, but it will continue to execute mouse presses after the mouse one button is released as long as the ctrl key is held. I am wondering if there is any kind of iteration that would allow me to signal a function that presses and releases the mouse but under the conditional that the same mouse button is pressed.(For example, ctrl must be held and rapid fire only executes when mouse button 1 is held down, as opposed to until ctrl is released).

Here is the code I am referring to

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsModifierPressed("lctrl") then
        repeat  
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                repeat
                    PressMouseButton(1)
                    Sleep(15)
                    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end             
        until not IsModifierPressed("lctrl")
    end         
end
```

I am wondering if there is any kind of iteration that would allow me to signal a function that presses and releases the mouse but under the conditional that the same mouse button is pressed.(For example, ctrl must be held and rapid fire only executes when mouse button 1 is held down, as opposed to until ctrl is released).

Alternatives I have considered: binding fire to another key that isn't mouse button 1, and having it repeated when mouse button one is pressed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is you're trying to simultaneously read real status and simulate press/release the same mouse button.
The only way to resolve this problem is (as you have suggested) to bind fire to additional key.
For example, in the game config you assign both left mouse button and keyboard key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to "Fire". Please note that <kbd>P</kbd> without a modifier must be NOT assigned to any action in the game.
And your script would be the following:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsModifierPressed("lctrl") then
      repeat
         Sleep(15)
         PressKey("P")
         Sleep(15)
         ReleaseKey("P")
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) or not IsModifierPressed("lctrl")
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!! It works as anticipated except for the game isn't recognizing the 'p' strokes as weapon fire. It will however recognize the keystrokes in game chat. I wonder if this is what you meant by p without a modifier, could you please explain more in depth what that means?

Comment: P without modifier is simply key P without Ctrl,Alt,Shift.  Fire should be assigned to both Ctrl-P and MB1 in the game.  Does the game recognize fire when you're pressing Ctrl-P on your keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
      repeat
         Sleep(10)
         PressKey("P")
         Sleep(10)
         ReleaseKey("P")
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) or not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**