# Logitech Lua combining Rapid Fire with spray

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

So basically, this is what my script looks like at the moment, it’s a rapid fire macro and reduces the recoil of the guns, however I can never spray with this script for some reason as it’s very slow because I guess it’s reducing the recoil. I was wondering if I could shoot like 4, 5 bullets without any recoil (only auto shoot while holding mouse 3 not while tapping.) and continue with spray like normal spray without any delays while already holding mouse3. So 4 bullets no recoil and rest the regular spray on the same cycle. If that makes any sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```lua
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);

function OnEvent(event, arg) 
    if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
            repeat  
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                    repeat
                        PressMouseButton(1)
                        Sleep(15)
                        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
                end             
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end   
    end
end
```

Comment: the code from this question seem very similar does the answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58121181/rapid-fire-with-logitech-lua-script

Comment: No sir,I think  what the other script does Is the rapid fire only activates when ctrl key is pressed. What I am trying to do is when I hold mouse2, it auto shoots  4,5 Bullets only while HOLDING not while tapping then regular spray after the rapid fire.

Comment: `it’s a rapid fire macro and reduces the recoil of the guns` - No.  Your script is a pure rapid fire.  It does not reduce recoil.  Are you talking about some other script, not the one you have posted?

Comment: Yes it is a rapid fire script, but when you rifle with the rapid fire script, thé bursts are accurate as hell with 3,4 bullets going straight depending on what gun you are using, that’s why I call it a no recoil script even tho it’s a rapid fire script. What I need help with is forcing the script to rapid fire 4 bullets and then regular spray after the script is done shooting four bullets, basically this script with only 4 bullets and then regular spray....( Guess it is impossible with lua, but somehow I manage to get it working for Oscar macro, bloody mouse.)

Comment: So, you're pressing right mouse button to turn rapid fire on.  And all you want now is just to simply release RMB after 4 bullets despite of you're still keeping RMB pressed physically?

Comment: That is right sir, however  as the 4 clicks are done, rmb should just function as a normal left click on the same cycle. Literally a regular spray right after the 4 clicks are done.. without no delays in between the macro and the regular left click spray.(that’s why I call it a combining 4 bursts and a regular spray if it’s posssible). Only rapid fire while holding rmb thought so I should be able tap as well instead of just spamming 4 bullets at once.

Comment: `Literally a regular spray right after the 4 clicks are done` - How exactly the script should simulate "regular spray"?  Does it mean: long RMB press = 4 bullet burst, short RMB press = single bullet?  `rmb should just function as a normal left click on the same cycle` - what means "on the same cycle"?

Comment: the script stops right after 4 bullets are shot as seen in this video https://streamable.com/wiy876, it should just function as a regular left click after that like this https://streamable.com/lqgyn3. i am able to do this because i am pressing left click right after the script is done spamming 4 bullets. by same cycle i meant, say for this script there is 20 bullets only 4 bullets are being shot then it stops shooting unless u repress the left key again the script stops right after right 4 bullets are shot,it should just function as a regular left click after that.

Comment: i was wondering if it is possbile to merge 4 bullets rapid fire merged with left click right after 4 bullets are being shot like this https://streamable.com/vhk6v8 but  WITHout any delays like seen in this video while only holding right click, i was able to do that because i pressed left click right afterthe script spammed its 4 bullets.

Comment: Ok, so `regular spray` means "press and hold LMB".  Answer updated.

Comment: Yes sir, can the pauses also be removed between the 4 bullet spam. You shoot a first bullet and there’s like a half sec or ms pause after the 2nd bullet shoots with the rest. https://streamable.com/wiy876 can it be just 4 bullets without any pauses between them. Thank you again for taking your time to look into this..

Comment: Make sure you're running exactly my script.  Just erase your old script and copy my as-is.

Comment: Thank you very much you are a legend, this is what i wanted  and how would i combine this bunny script to the script that you made so both works at the same time ` ` function OnEvent(event, arg) if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then repeat Sleep(15) PressKey("SPACEBAR") Sleep(15) ReleaseKey("SPACEBAR") until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) end end 
the script shoots 3 bullets while holding right button, so to change it to 4 bullets i just need to change the 2*fire delay to 4? i am guessing because it worked. –.don't understand these numbers :P again thank you very much

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: hey so if i were to use mouse 1 as in left click for this script instead of right-click, how would i do it, i tried changing it to 1, it only shoots 1 bullet

Comment: You should use `@e` in your comment to "call" me (I will receive a notification).

Comment: It is possible to rapid fire with LMB, but you must assign another button to fire in the game. Can you assign, for example, keyboard key P as the only way for action "fire"?  LMB must not be treated as "fire".

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff could you show me what mouse buttons do i have to change on script its not working for me when i change everything on script to mouse1, the lmb stops functioning. and is it possible to add this script after a default mouse1 click without any delays for example normal mouse click 2 without any delays or script after that auto execute this script after the 2 normal mouse clicks.

Comment: It's impossible to simultaneously simulate mouse button#1 press/release (for rapid fire) and monitor the state (down/up) of the physical mouse button#1.  The workaround is to introduce another key to shoot in the game (for example, keyboard key `P`) and simulate `P` press/release in the script while monitoring the physical mouse button#1 state.

Comment: `for example normal mouse click 2 without any delays` I don't understand what "delay" are you talking about.  The current version of the script simulates rapid fire after RMB press without any delay.

Comment: ah, this is how i was using the script, https://imgur.com/a/flBR4YO i was using my g8 mouse button to shoot which is near my lmb, it was kinda getting weird tahtswhy i thought it was possible with lmb too guess not (binded my g4 with g8 on the mouse settings changed the mouse clicks on scripts as well that way the script would read it as mouse button 1 when i press my g8

Comment: basically the script executes instantly when i press LMB,i would click mouse 1 then the 2nd time i click mouse 1 then the script executes.

Comment: imgur does not work for me.  I don't see the picture.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/Jq9H4cuC.png https://pasteboard.co/Jq9Hc7A.png

Comment: Ok, now I see your pictures - you are using button#8 instead of RMB. Yes, it's possible to make script run only after LMB double-click.  Usual "slow" LMB click would be a simple shoot without rapidfire.  I have appended new code to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local rapid_fire_delay = 15   -- delay between simulation of LMB press/release
local LMB_Pressed
do  -- initializing PRNG
   local dt = 0
   for c in GetDate():gmatch"." do
      dt = (dt % 65537 * 23456 + c:byte())
   end
   math.randomseed(dt)
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then   -- RMB press
      for j = 1, math.random(4, 5) do  -- first 4-5 bullets as rapid-fire
         PressMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(math.random(rapid_fire_delay, 2*rapid_fire_delay))
         ReleaseMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(math.random(rapid_fire_delay, 2*rapid_fire_delay))
         if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then return end  -- is RMB pressed?
      end
      PressMouseButton(1)
      LMB_Pressed = true
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 2 and LMB_Pressed then   -- RMB release
      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
      LMB_Pressed = false
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then 
      repeat 
         Sleep(15) 
         PressKey("SPACEBAR") 
         Sleep(15) 
         ReleaseKey("SPACEBAR") 
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) 
   end 
end
```

The line `for j = 1, math.random(4, 5) do` means "a random quantity from 4 to 5 bullets".
If you want exactly 3 bullets change this line to `for j = 1, 3 do`

---

**EDIT:**

This is instruction on how to make the rapidfire turn on only after LMB double-click.
Usual slow LMB click will not trigger rapidfire.

```
local Prev_LMB_Time, LMB_Pressed = 0
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
         local tm = GetRunningTime()
         tm, Prev_LMB_Time = tm - Prev_LMB_Time, tm
         if tm < 200 then  -- LMB double-click
            for j = 1, 100 do
               PressMouseButton(1)
               Sleep(1)
               ReleaseMouseButton(1)
               Sleep(1)
               if not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then return end
            end
         end
      end
      PressMouseButton(1)
      LMB_Pressed = true
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 and LMB_Pressed then
      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
      LMB_Pressed = false
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      repeat
         Sleep(15)
         PressKey("SPACEBAR")
         Sleep(15)
         ReleaseKey("SPACEBAR")
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
   end
end
```

Currently you have in GHUB:

```
Primary Click = G1
Back          = G4 G8
```

What you should do in GHUB (in this order):

1. Bind "Primary Click" to G8 (from now on, use button#8 instead of LMB)
2. Bind "Back" to G1
3. Set the script

```
Now you should have the following:
Primary Click = G8
Back          = G1 G4
```

Mouse button#8 is now "spare LMB" just in case LMB works incorrectly.