# Spamming Key with lua

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to create a script that spams w when windows key is pressed, but it says Lua Error (5): invalid argument: modifier not specified, this is my script.. any help would be greatly appreciated

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if  IsModifierPressed ("appkey") then --windows key is appkey i am assuming
      repeat
         Sleep(100)
         PressKey("w")
         Sleep(100)
         ReleaseKey("w")
      until  not IsModifierPressed ("appkey")
   end
end
```

and also I am trying to make a quick switch script as well, if I press the right mouse button and left mouse button at the same time then it would automatically press the key q, but I get the error saying Syntax Error:Line:2

```
     EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true) 
        function OnEvent(event, arg)
     if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == "3","1" then
         repeat
         PressKey("q") 
        Sleep(2) 
        ReleaseKey("q") 
        end 
 end
```

Comment: Please post the **full** contents of the error--errors usually contain helpful info that tells you exactly what the actual error is, such as line numbers. Also, you can just use `while` on your first line instead of `if` for the loop, rather than nesting a `repeat until` that checks the opposite condition.

Comment: Is that the exact error? Copy+paste it in.

Comment: done updated thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- if I press the right mouse button and left mouse button at the same time 
-- then it would automatically press the key q

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true) 
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg < 3 then
      repeat
         Sleep(10)
         if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then 
            PressKey("q") 
            Sleep(10) 
            ReleaseKey("q") 
         else
            break 
         end 
      until nil
   end
end
```

Comment: thankyou very much again legend, is there literally anything i can do to support you? so about the spamming w when windows key is pressed is it possible with lua, i have a Logitech keyboard?

Comment: `about the spamming w when windows key is pressed is it possible` No.  You can determine if a key is pressed only for the following keys: 1) modifier keys by calling IsModifierPressed (see Piglet's answer) and 2) G1,G2,G3,G4,... keys by handling the G_PRESSED / G_RELEASED events.  G keys are different on different keyboards, for example on my G413 they are F1-F12. BTW what's your keyboard model?

Comment: using g513 atm, damn.. i could literally assign macro to any button on the Razer ultimate keyboard, didn't even realize until today u cant assign any macros to the keys besides the G's u stated.

Comment: Can you write a Lua/Python/whatever scripts for key press events on Razer ultimate keyboard?

Comment: No, just macro not a script.

Comment: With macro only it's impossible to make some things.  For example, it's impossible to implement 'spam q while both LMB and RMB are pressed'.  IMO, possibility to write scripts is much more valuable.

Comment: Yes sir, on the rapid fire script that you made, can I use my left click to shoot instead of using my right click, I am using g502 currently. Thanks

Comment: The script in my answer is symmetric for LMB and RMB. It does not matter which button is pressed first.  Just press and hold both of them.

Comment: I was referring to this one that you made, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62541412/logitech-lua-combining-rapid-fire-with-spray?noredirect=1#comment110964282_62541412

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual the modifier must be one of the following strings:

```
"lalt", "ralt", "alt", "lshift", "rshift", "shift", "lctrl", "rctrl", "ctrl"
```

`"appkey"` is not in that list. Hence you get an error. Please read manuals.

https://douile.github.io/logitech-toggle-keys/APIDocs.pdf  Page 17

Windows key is "lgui" and "rgui" and it is just a key, not a modifier. Modifiers modify the meaning of a key, as the name indicates.